# CatBoost eval_set not working inside scikit-learn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, catboost

I am trying to pass `X_valid` dataset into the `eval_set` parameters in the fit function from CatBoost library (this is the link to the [documentation](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboostregressor_fit)) but I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Pipeline.fit does not accept the cat_features parameter. You can pass parameters to specific steps of your pipeline using the stepname__parameter format, e.g. `Pipeline.fit(X, y, logisticregression__sample_weight=sample_weight)`.
```

The code that I am running is

```
catboost_model = CatBoostClassifier(learning_rate=0.02, eval_metric='AUC')

pipeline = Pipeline([("classifer", catboost_model)])

cat_columns = ['frontend_client_type']

X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(df[cat_columns], df['label'], test_size=0.2)

pipeline = pipeline.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    cat_features=cat_columns,
    classifer__eval_set=[(X_valid, y_valid)],
)
```

My synthetic dataframe is

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'frontend_client_type':['android', 'android', 'ios', 'web', 'android'],
                   'label':[True, True, False, False, True]})
```

Comment: You should replace `cat_features=cat_columns` with `classifer__cat_features=cat_columns` when fitting the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Use `classifer__cat_features=cat_columns` in `pipeline.fit` instead of `cat_features=cat_columns`.

According to official documentation,

> "The purpose of the pipeline is to assemble several steps that can be cross-validated together while setting different parameters. For this, it enables setting parameters of the various steps using their names and the parameter name separated by a '__'"[sklearn pipeline documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html)